# Dibujar en pantalla .net MAUI

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

Quiero dibujar un circulo de dimensiones aleatorias y color aleatorio en .net MAUI. Además no podemos usar codigo behind sino que debemos usar el MVVM. He realizado la clase circulo, la clase del VM y el codigo front pero sin embargo cuando ejecuto el programa no me pinta nada en la pantalla.

**Clase del circulo:**

```
    using System.Drawing;

namespace Entidades
{
    public class clsCirculo
    {
        #region Atributos
        private Color colorCirculo;
        private float posX;
        private float posY;
        private float radio;
        #endregion

        #region Propiedades

        public Color ColorCirculo
        {
            get { return colorCirculo; }
            set { colorCirculo = value; }
        }

        public float PosX
        {
            get { return posX; }
            set { posX = value; }
        }
        public float PosY
        {
            get { return posY; }
            set { posY = value; }
        }
        
        public float Radio
        {
            get { return radio; }
            set
            {
                radio = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public clsCirculo()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            colorCirculo = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(255), r.Next(255), r.Next(255));
            posX = r.Next(0, 255);
            posY = r.Next(0, 255);
            radio = r.Next(0, 70);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Metodos
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Clase del ViewModel**

```
using Entidades;
using _11_JuegoSignalR.Hubs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Javax.Security.Auth;

namespace _11_JuegoMAUI.ViewModels
{
    public class clsJuegoVM
    {
        #region Atributos
        clsCirculo circulo;
        #endregion

        #region Propiedades
        public clsCirculo Circulo
        {
            get { return circulo; }
            set { circulo = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public clsJuegoVM()
        {
            circulo = new clsCirculo();

            

        }
        #endregion

        #region Metodos


        
        
        #endregion
    } 
}
```

**Código front**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="_11_JuegoMAUI.JuegoPage"
             xmlns:model ="clr-namespace:_11_JuegoMAUI.ViewModels">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <model:clsJuegoVM/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Path Fill="{Binding Circulo.ColorCirculo}"
                  >
                <Path.Data>
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50"
                     RadiusX="{Binding Circulo.Radio}"
                     RadiusY="{Binding Circulo.Radio}" />
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Bindeo las propiedades del circulo a los campos que me dice utilizar la documentacion de maui

Más adelante tendré que introducir métodos para conectar con signalR por eso necesitamos el modelo MVVM y no se puede hacer directamente con el codigo behind. Además mi profesor siempre nos dice que el ódigo behind es una mala práctica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si cambias el circulo por un `Label`

```
<Label Text="{Binding Circulo.Radio}"
           FontSize="18"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

Te darás cuenta que funciona. Y es que hay "algo" que no te está permitiendo hacer binding a `EllipseGeometry`, desconozco el motivo.

Una posible solución es ocupar `Resources` en vez de `BindingContext`

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:model ="clr-namespace:MauiApp6.model"
             x:Class="MauiApp6.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <model:clsJuegoVM x:Key="Juego"></model:clsJuegoVM>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ScrollView>

        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Path Fill="Red">

                <Path.Data >

                    <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" 
                     RadiusX="{Binding Circulo.Radio, Source={StaticResource Juego}}" 
                     RadiusY="{Binding Circulo.Radio, Source={StaticResource Juego}}" />
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

---

Honestamente he respondido porque no puedo dejar pasar esta frase

> Además mi profesor siempre nos dice que el código behind es una mala
> práctica

Este es un error conceptual muy grave. En .net existe muchas tecnologías que ocupan `code behind` para las vistas. Donde estas se separan en 2

- code behind
- Código UI (XAML, RAZOR, HTML)

La suma de esas 2 partes hace la vista. **El error está en creer que solo el XAML es la vista** y no es así.

Si tu escribes en el `code behind` código que solo afecta a la vista, sigues cumpliendo la separación de responsabilidades que propone MVVM o MVC

Algunos años atrás cuando XAML estaba más de moda, vi muchas personas que se rompían la cabeza tratando de no dejar código alguno en el `code behind`, debido al mal entendimiento de la tecnología y el paradigma. Y es que además hay algunos escenarios donde ni siquiera es posible hacerlo, en otros la complejidad es demasiado grande para considerarlo un beneficio, y a todo eso debes sumar que es complejo depurar un XAML (tú mismo caso es un ejemplo de ello)

Y ahora a modo personal, el uso de paradigmas como MVVM debe ser en favor de mejorar el código y la mantención del mismo. Si existe un caso donde es mejor romper el paradigma, pues se debe romper. En la programación unos de los peores errores es ser dogmatico.

Comment: Perfecto lo probaré y le comentare a mi profesor lo q me has dicho. Muchas graciass